# node.js remove event listener not working

Tags: javascript, events, node.js

I'm trying to remove some eventlistener like this:

```
    var callback = function () {
      someFun(someobj)
    }

    console.log(callback)

    e.once("5", callback);

    uponSomeOtherStuffHappening('',
    function() {
      console.log(e.listeners("5")[0])
      e.removeListener(inTurns, callback)
    })
```

But it doesn't work.

The first console log shows:

```
[Function]
```

The second one shows:

```
[Function: g]
```

Why are they different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of once() inserts a function g() to remove your listener after one call.

From events.js:

```
EventEmitter.prototype.once = function(type, listener) {
  if ('function' !== typeof listener) {
    throw new Error('.once only takes instances of Function');
  }

  var self = this;
  function g() {
    self.removeListener(type, g);
    listener.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  g.listener = listener;
  self.on(type, g);

  return this;
};
```

So, if you did this:

```
console.log(e.listeners("5")[0].listener);
```

they'd be the same.

Comment: thanks, looks like i ran into a bug. I should upgrade from this stupid old version...